# How to split long string after first space after 100 characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a long string and want to split it into segments of +/- 100 characters if it has more than 100 otherwise not.
That means I have for example this string:

## string input

```
"asld asö öasdn askdn asklcanscklans cakslcna acsklcnasclk ncaslkcnas casld asö öasdn askdn asklcanscklans cakslcna acsklcnasclk ncaslkcnas c"
```

## and need these 2 strings out of it

```
1: "asld asö öasdn askdn asklcanscklans cakslcna acsklcnasclk ncaslkcnas casld asö öasdn askdn asklcanscklans"
2: "cakslcna acsklcnasclk ncaslkcnas c"
```

As you can see, I need to split them after the first space, after the 100th character.

I'm clueless how to do that with .split()

Comment: Hint: don't split, try to match. Here's a start `/[\s\S]{1,100}\S*/g`

Comment: You can't do that only with `split()`. split is not the good method here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `string.split(/(.{100}\S*)\s/).filter(function(e){return e;});`

Comment: this one doesnt return the firt 100+ chars

Comment: Are you need to have only one string ```100 chars``` and one ```all other chars```?

Comment: No. I need all characters. But splitted into chunks of each 100 or more depending on the first space after each 100th character. Your example doesn't output the first chars... or am I wrong? see: http://jsfiddle.net/ExSz6/

Comment: Oh, sorry. I see the problem.
How about ```string.split(/(.{100}\S*)\s/).filter(function(e){return e;});```

Answer (score 5):

You can use indexOf to search your string for a specified character, indexOf also provides an optional argument for a starting index in your string, giving you the position from which you can substring or do whatever you need to do:

```
string.indexOf(' ',100);
```

If you want to perform further splits you can use a loop to run back over the results and perform the same action.

There are some suggestions of using regex here which may be fine, all I would say is if you want to use Regex then go away and get an understanding of what the pattern does. Using code you don't understand makes your life difficult later on.

Comment: Consider adding a suggestion on how to split the string, like `var index = string.indexOf(' ', 100); var part1 = string.substring(0, index + 1); var part2 = string.substring(index + 1

Comment: I was going to do this but I don't agree with debraining the entire process, I think the thread has enough detail for the asker to write a suitable solution.

Comment: Small update for people reading this useful response years later: indexOf has been replaced by index.

Comment: @aschultz I'm not seeing any evidence of that, could you provide a link to something that confirms it please?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the first space after position 100 as:

```ecmascript
var index = string.indexOf(' ', 100);
```

You want to split *after* this space, so your second part starts at:

```ecmascript
var splitPoint = string.indexOf(' ', 100) + 1;
```

If the string is not 100 characters long, or there is no space after position 100, then `splitPoint` is zero (because `indexOf` returns -1), and you don't want to split.

So you can split the string as:

```ecmascript
if (splitPoint > 0) {
  var part1 = string.substring(0, splitPoint);
  var part2 = string.substring(splitPoint);
  // Do something with the parts.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), you can use a `RegExp` with split, and capture a part of it using capture groups.

```
var s = "asld asö öasdn askdn asklcanscklans cakslcna acsklcnasclk ncaslkcnas casld asö öasdn askdn asklcanscklans cakslcna acsklcnasclk ncaslkcnas c";
s.split(/(.{100}[^\s]*)\s/);

// 1 : "asld asö öasdn askdn asklcanscklans cakslcna acsklcnasclk ncaslkcnas casld asö öasdn askdn asklcanscklans"
// 2 : "cakslcna acsklcnasclk ncaslkcnas c"
```

And to remove the empty element(s), you can use the `filter` method :

```
s.split(/(.{100}[^\s]*)\s/).filter(function(s) {
    return s.length > 0;
});
```

Comment: This is overkill, also the OP is probably not going to be helped by a regex which is possibly above his/her current level of understanding.

Comment: I don't think it is so difficult to understand, but you need to remove the empty element at the begining of the array (with the shift method for example) and to explain that it is possible to capture a part of the delimiter with a capture group.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte The empty element is a problem that cannot be solved by using `split`. I edited my answer. The usage of capture group in split is explained in the documentation, I'll add a link.

Comment: Since the empty element is at the begining, you can do that too: `var arr = s.split(/(.{100}\S*)\s/); arr.shift(); console.log(arr);` (and you avoid to parse all the array.)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, but there are other empty spaces when the string is longer.

Comment: Indeed, the only other empty result you can have with this pattern is at the end of the array (if the string ends with a space and have at least 100 characters before.)

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do that using substr

```
var your_string = "asld asö öasdn askdn asklcanscklans cakslcna acsklcnasclk ncaslkcnas casld asö öasdn askdn asklcanscklans cakslcna acsklcnasclk ncaslkcnas c"

var string1 = your_string.substr(0,105);
var string2 = your_string.substr(106,your_string.length)
```

Comment: i could if i knew the length of the string and 105 is variable in my case